# RMAN archive logs are no longer automatically being generated?

Tags: oracle, backup, rman, archive-log

**To preface...** I have mentioned this before in a previous question, but I'll add it again: Our Senior Oracle DBA has just recently passed away, and I've been taking over. My level of experience is just a junior level. So there is a lot I still don't understand. So I appreciate all the tips I can get, as this is a very frightening position for me.

**The Question...** We have been going through a series of storage issues. There was a point when our filesystem filled to 100% and all our backups stopped recording. We have resolved the space issue, but since then, I noticed that our Archivelog backups are no longer being generated automatically even though they're still scheduled on EM. I checked OEM job activity and it shows that the archivelog backup "successfully" completed but with an empty output log. What's going on? The RMAN configuration appears to be the same.

Just FYI, I don't know how to automate RMAN backups. After our senior passed, I have just been dealing with what was already automated.

```
RMAN> backup device type disk tag 'ARCHIVELOGS_BACKUP_062421100006' archivelog a
ll not backed up delete all input;
Starting backup at 2021-06-24 10:00:11
current log archived
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=5066 device type=DISK
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting compressed archived log backup set
channel ORA_DISK_1: specifying archived log(s) in backup set
input archived log thread=1 sequence=31060 RECID=93036 STAMP=1076061622
channel ORA_DISK_1: starting piece 1 at 2021-06-24 10:00:23
channel ORA_DISK_1: finished piece 1 at 2021-06-24 10:00:38
piece handle=/RMAN/FLASH/WEBPRD01/WEBPRD01/backupset/2021_06_24/o1_mf_annnn_ARCH
IVELOGS_BACKUP_0_jf93zr01_.bkp tag=ARCHIVELOGS_BACKUP_062421100006 comment=NONE
channel ORA_DISK_1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:15
channel ORA_DISK_1: deleting archived log(s)
archived log file name=/RMAN/FLASH/WEBPRD01/WEBPRD01/archivelog/2021_06_24/o1_mf
_1_31060_jf93zjxr_.arc RECID=93036 STAMP=1076061622
archived log file name=/ora06/oracle/arch/WEBPRD01/log_1_31060_916831033.arc REC
ID=93035 STAMP=1076061622
Finished backup at 2021-06-24 10:00:39

Starting Control File and SPFILE Autobackup at 2021-06-24 10:00:39
piece handle=/RMAN/FLASH/WEBPRD01/WEBPRD01/autobackup/2021_06_24/o1_mf_s_1076061
639_jf9407w8_.bkp comment=NONE
Finished Control File and SPFILE Autobackup at 2021-06-24 10:00:40


RMAN> exit;

Recovery Manager complete.

Checking RMAN repository settings...
Backup Succeeded.
```

Comment: Post a copy of your RMAN script and the output in the question, please. The actual formatted text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: @pmdba Forgive my ignorance, but how do I obtain the script? Is it available through the actual job on OEM?

Comment: See here: https://cdonoghuedba.wordpress.com/2015/01/23/getting-an-rman-script-from-the-oem-repository-views/

Comment: The query this link mentioned to run returned ``no rows selected``

Comment: _"The query this link mentioned to run returned no rows selected"_  This is where you need to be updating youir original post with _formatted_ copy and paste of the full query and full result.

Comment: Updated. @EdStevens

Comment: @Phillip, was your job name 'FULL_BACKUP'? Do you need to modify the query to match the job name in your system?

Comment: So sorry, I did not realize that was what it meant. I edited the post with an output of an archivelog schedule that did not generate anything.

Comment: All, I believe I have discovered the issue. Thank you, the link @pmdba posted has really helped me.